# Can I assign two static IP addresses to one VM on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have two windows server VMs in Google Cloud Platform each has it's own static IP address.  I want to temporarily send the traffic from one of those static IPs to the other server so both static IPs would now be going to just one of the VMs.

The goal is to move traffic from one to the other while doing some server maintenance.

From the cloud console I can go to the management page for static ip addresses and Change the routing of the IP address to the other VM rather simply but it gives me this warning:

> The static IP address currently attached to instance vm2 (Zone
>   us-central1-a) will be detached. Static IP addresses not attached to
>   an instance or load balancer are billed at an hourly rate Pricing
>   details

That sounds like I'm going to replace VM2s Static IP with VM1s. That will interfere with all the traffic already going to VM2.  Is there a way to accomplish this so that for a time both IP addresses are pointing to the same VM? I'll need to switch them back the other direction when I'm done of course.

Perhaps I'm going about this all wrong from the start, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might instead want to build a load balancer or some other network object that will listen on VM1's IP and forward the traffic to VM2's IP. Then when you're done with VM1, you can either give it its IP back or simply make it another target of the load balancer. Eventually you can retire VM2's IP as a target for traffic and with a load balancer it will be much easier to perform maintenance in the future, as well as replace the VMs, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually assign two IP addresses to one VM (with some restrictions) by [creating instances with multiple network interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces). However, I don’t think it will be possible to achieve your goal this way, because of the limitations it implies. For example:

> -Each network interface configured in a single instance must be attached to a different VPC network.
>
> -You can only configure network interfaces when you create the instance.

I would agree with [Todd](https://serverfault.com/users/213609/todd-wilcox): A better approach is to configure a load balancer. I recommend you to read the [overview of Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview) to determine which type of load balancing suits your application better. For example, if you decide to go with [Network Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/) you can follow the steps described [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/setting-up-network).

Answer (score 2):

You can get multiple external IPs for one VM instance

By default, VM will be assigned with an ephemeral external IP, you can promote it to static external IP, which will remain unchanged after stop and restart.
Extra external IPs have to be attached to forwarding rules which point to the VM. You can use (or promote to) static IPs as well.

The command you may want to use:

Create a TargetInstance for your VM instance:

```
gcloud compute target-instances create <target-instance-name> --instance <instance-name> --zone=<zone>
```

Please check [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963164/multiple-ip-addresses-on-a-single-google-compute-engine-instance)